# Closing a Game(object) from tkinter popup

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I need to make a popup window that will end a game. The popup window can be either inside or outside of the game class. At the moment, it only closes one canvas, how can I make it close itself, canvas and canvas2 when the user clicks "Close"

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Game")
        self._master = master
        self._canvas2 = tk.Canvas(master, bg='grey', width=300, height=50)
        self._canvas2.pack()
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg='grey', width=300, height=200)
        self._canvas.pack()


    #if conditions met, open popup:
    self.popup()

    def popup(self):
        end = Toplevel()
        end.title("End")
        msg = Message(end, text="The game has ended")
        msg.pack()
        button = Button(end, text="Close", command=self._canvas.destroy)
        button.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Other options I have tried:
`command=self.destroy`, `command=self.exit()`, `command=self.quit()`

Please note, Game must be an object due to assignment restrictions. The initialisations at the bottom were also provided for me. The popup does not have to be a toplevel window (but it does need to use tkinter), this is just the one I have attempted to implement.

Comment: have you tried creating your own function that deletes both canvases, and calling that function from your button?

Comment: Just tried, no luck. `command=self.close()`, `def close(self):`, `self._canvas.destroy, self._canvas2.destroy` Nothing happens. Also tried putting it outside of the class (and removing self) but this also does not work. Have tried calling it on app, root....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create your own function to call from the button:

```
...
button = Button(end, text="Close", command=self.close)
...
def close(self):
    self._canvas.destroy()
    self._canvas2.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to append the parentheses. I found that using this, the canvas windows were destroyed, but the main window and popup were still open.
Calling `self._master.destroy()` closed everything.